# Expected Times for Exponential Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Two craftsman A,B are making birdhouses at rates 2,3 per hour respectively. 
What is the expected time until each of the craftsman finish making one bird house?

So I have tried conditioning on each:

Suppose A finishes first, then the expected time should depend only on the time B takes to finish, E(B) = 1/3 or 20 minutes.

Suppose B finishes first, then the expected time should depend only on the time A takes to finish, E(A) = 1/2 or 30 minutes.

Next step is that I multiply each by probability of finishing first
P(A Finish first) = 2/(2+3)
P(B Finish first) = 3/(2+3)

(1/3)*(2/5) + (1/2)*(3/5) = 13/30 or 26 minutes.

However, I noticed that this is flawed because I do not account for the case where A and B finish at the same time, but I do not know how to account for the probability that both complete the birdhouse at the same time. I could try P(A)*P(B) by independence, but I do not have an explicit time to complete the computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A be distributed according to Exp(2) and B be distributed according to Exp(3).

What you are looking for is E[ max(A,B) ] = E[ A+B-min(A,B) ] = E[A]+E[B]-E[ min(A,B) ].

We know that the minimum of two exponentials with parameters $p_1, p_2$ is distributed according to exponential with the sum of the two parameters $p_1 + p_2$ as parameter. So min(A,B) is distributed according to Exp(5).

Also, the expectation of an exponential with parameter p is 1/p.

Thus, E[ max(A,B) ] = E[A]+E[B]-E[ min(A,B) ] = 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/5 = 19/30

Comment: So max[A,B] = -min[-A,-B], we can add A+B to both terms in the min function to get A+B-min[B,A] = A+B-min[A,B] correct?
This method is much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are correct, another way to see it is that max(A,B) + min(A,B) = A+B for any numbers. e.g. max(3,5) + min(3,5) = 5 + 3.

Comment: I woke up today and thought, what if I extended this to 3 craftsman A,B,C such that 2,3,4 are the new rates. It seems like the trick no longer works because I would get E[A+B+C-min(B+C,A+C,A+B)] and B+C is not exponential.

Comment: Lets assume that A < B < C. You can check that A+B+C - min(A,B) - min(B,C) - min(A,C) + min(A,B,C) = max(A,B,C). By symmetry this works for any ordering of A,B,C. So you can still apply the trick. E[max(A,B,C)] = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 - 1/5 - 1/7 - 1/6 + 1/9. This works in general, using inclusion exclusion.